# Result of glm() for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

This might be a trivial question but I don't know where to find answers. I'm wondering when using `glm()` for logistic regression in R, if the response variable `Y` has factor values 1 or 2, does the result of `glm()` correspond to `logit(P(Y=1))` or `logit(P(Y=2))`? What if `Y` has logical values `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just test it yourself?

```r
output_bool <- c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(25, 75)), rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(75, 25)))
output_num <- c(rep(c(2, 1), c(25, 75)), rep(c(2, 1), c(75, 25)))
output_fact <- factor(output_num)
var <- rep(c("unlikely", "likely"), each = 100)

glm(output_bool ~ var, binomial)
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = output_bool ~ var, family = binomial)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  varunlikely  
#>       1.099       -2.197  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 199 Total (i.e. Null);  198 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       277.3 
#> Residual Deviance: 224.9     AIC: 228.9
glm(output_num ~ var, binomial)
#> Error in eval(family$initialize): y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
glm(output_fact ~ var, binomial)
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = output_fact ~ var, family = binomial)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  varunlikely  
#>       1.099       -2.197  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 199 Total (i.e. Null);  198 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       277.3 
#> Residual Deviance: 224.9     AIC: 228.9
```

So, we get the correct answer if we use TRUE and FALSE, an error if we use 1 and 2 as numbers, and the correct result if we use 1 and 2 as a factor with two levels provided the TRUE value has a higher factor level than the FALSE. However, we have to be careful in how our factors are ordered or we will get the wrong result:

```r
output_fact <- factor(output_fact, levels = c("2", "1"))
glm(output_fact ~ var, binomial)
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = output_fact ~ var, family = binomial)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  varunlikely  
#>      -1.099        2.197  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 199 Total (i.e. Null);  198 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       277.3 
#> Residual Deviance: 224.9     AIC: 228.9
```

(Notice the intercept and coefficient have flipped signs)

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Testing is good. If you want the documentation, it's in `?binomial` (which is the same as `?family`):

> For the ‘binomial’ and ‘quasibinomial’ families the response can
> be specified in one of three ways:

> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not
>    having the first level (and hence usually of having the
>    second level).

> 2. As a numerical vector with values between ‘0’ and ‘1’,
>    interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the
>    total number of cases given by the ‘weights’).

> 3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the
>    number of successes and the second the number of failures.

It doesn't explicitly say what happens in the logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) case; for that you have to know that, when coercing logical to numeric values, `FALSE` → 0 and `TRUE` → 1.